# How to access all variables in all databases from PLC (without specifying the name of database or variable)?

Tags: python, plc, opc-ua

In the plc database i have a database named "status" which has a variable named "Temperature". Since I know the names, I access the value of this variable like this:

```
from opcua import Client
client = Client("url")
client.connect()
temperature = client.get_node("ns=3;s=\"status\".\"Temperature\"").get_value()
```

Now how can I get this information without knowledge of database or variable name? I want a general code that takes everything from a given PLC url.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Do you want to read the data registers?

Comment: In the plc database i have a database named "status" which has a variable named "Temperature". Since I know the names, I access the value of this variable like this:

temperature= client.get_node("ns=3;s=\"Temperature\"").get_value()

Now how can I get this information without knowledge of database or variable name?

Comment: I think you're better updating your original question with that as an edit. I only know how to read registers for PLCs, not a database.

Comment: I very well may be wrong with the edit I just did. Please revert it if I tagged wrongly, and it's on my head, not the OP's

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `Browse` service.

Check the documentation or examples for whichever toolkit you're using.

Comment: Even that method asks for parameters: 

    def browse(self, parameters):
          .....

Comment: Are you unable to provide the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
from opcua import Client
client = Client("url")
client.connect()
node = client.get_objects_node()
def walk(node):
    a = node.get_children()
    for child in a:
        if child.get_children():
            walk(child)
        else:
            try:
                print(type(child.get_browse_name()), child.get_value())
            except:
                pass
```